# Finding the projections associated to the direct sum decomposition of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, direct-sum, projection, projection-matrices

**PROBLEM STATEMENT**

Hi all. First, I am given two vector spaces:

Let $V = \mathbb{R}^4$. Consider the following subspaces:
$V_1 = \{(x,y,z,t)\ : x = y = z\}, V_2=[(2,1,1,1)], V_3 =[(2,2,1,1)]$

And let $V = M_n(\mathbb{k})$. Consider the following subspaces:

$V_1 = \{(a_{ij}) \in V : a_{ij} = 0,\forall i < j\}$

$V_2 = \{(a_{ij}) \in V : a_{ij} = 0,\forall i > j\}$

$V_3 = \{(a_{ij}) \in V: a_{ij} = 0, \forall i \neq j\}$

Prove that for both statements it is true that $V = V_1 \oplus V_2 \oplus V_3$

Find the projections associated to both decompositions.

**ATTEMPT AT A SOLUTION**

So for both it was fairly trivial to prove the direct sum. To be explicit about my method, in the first case I took the basis of $V_1$ to be $\{(1,0,0,0),(0,0,0,1)\}$ (from $\{(1,1,1,0),(0,0,0,1)\}$ given by the definition of the subspace) and for $V_2, V_3$ the given vectors. I used these as columns, performed matrix operations to reach row echelon form, and thereby discovered that I could form a diagonal matrix and that each column was linearly independent.

From there, the sum clearly gave me a general vector in $V$, and by the definition of their linear independence the intersection between the spaces is necessarily $\{0\}$. Therefore we have a direct sum in the first case.

In the second case, the basis of $V_1$ is a matrix with entries of $1$ above the diagonal and $0$ along and below the diagonal, $V_2$ is $0$ along and above the diagonal and $1$ below, and the basis of $V_3$ is a diagonal matrix with $0$ above and below.

Again the direct sum is clear.

**HELP NEEDED**

However, I do not know how to find the projections associated to these decompositions. I do know the definition of a a projection. Is there some intuitive way to see what it would be like here or in similar cases, or do I need to apply the formula $P_x = A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$? If so, could I see an example from the first case?

Comment: How is $\{(1,0,0,0),(0,0,0,1)\}$ a basis for $V_1$?

Comment: I see what you mean, but it cannot possibly be $\{(1,1,1,0),(0,0,0,1)\}$ , can it? What would it be?

Comment: In fact, it is. All elements of $V_1$ are of the form $(a,a,a,b)=a(1,1,1,0)+b(0,0,0,1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider, for instance the projection of $\mathbb{R}^4$ on $V_1$. Since $\bigl((1,0,0,0),(0,0,0,1)\bigr)$ is a basis of $V_1$, $\bigl((2,1,1,1)\bigr)$ is a basis of $V_2$, and $\bigl(2,2,1,1)\bigr)$ is a basis of $V_3$, you consider the linear map $P\colon\mathbb{R}^4\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^4$ such that

- $P(1,0,0,0)=(1,0,0,0)$;
- $P(0,0,0,1)=(0,0,0,1)$;
- $P(2,1,1,1)=(0,0,0,0)$;
- $P(2,2,1,1)=(0,0,0,0)$.

This is the projection of $\mathbb{R}^4$ onto $V_1$ based upon the decomposition $\mathbb{R}^4=V_1\oplus V_2\oplus V_3$.

Comment: I see. And therefore, to take as an example $V_2$, the projection would be $P(2, 1, 1, 1) = (2, 1, 1, 1)$ where the other basis vectors map to the 0 vector?

And in the second case, the projection of $V_1$ would be a matrix with entries of $1$ above the diagonal, and the other two basis vectors map to the 0 vector, $V_3$ maps to a diagonal matrix, etc? 

That is to say, for each subspace the projection maps the basis of that subspace to itself, and the basis vectors of the other subspaces to the 0 vector?

Comment: @JakeS Yes, that's right.

Comment: I see. I'll accept your answer as the solution momentarily, and you've been a great help! If I can I would like to ask your assistance in one further problem - given the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ generated by the vector $(1,-1$), how would I find the projection along the subspace generated by $(1,2)$?

Comment: It's the endomorphism $P$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $P(1,-1)=(1,-1)$ and that $P(1,2)=0$.

Comment: I understand, but is that statement a solution to the problem, or is it necessary to show a matrix which performs that computation?

Comment: @JakeS That depends upon the way the problem is stated. But the matrix (with espect to the standard basis) is no hard to find. It is$$\frac13\begin{bmatrix}2&-1\\-2&
1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Forgive me for extending the discussion, but could you outline your process for finding that matrix? The computations I was doing did not give me the same result.

Comment: You're after a matrix $P=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, right? And it has to be such that $P.(1,-1)=(1,-1)$ and that $P.(1,2)=(0,0)$. This leads to the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}a-b=1\\c-d=-1\\a+2b=0\\c+2d=0.\end{array}\right.$$Solve the system and you'll get $P$.

Comment: Ahh, thank you, I had made a calculation error when I framed the problem with matrices. Question closed! You've been a great help.

Comment: @JakeS I'm glad I could help.